# WebView in Flash?

Tags: flash, webview, flash-cs5

Is it possible to have a "webview" in a Flash file? Basically I need something akin to an iframe that fills my flash document.

Comment: Are you going to export using AIR? If so there is the `StageWebView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in Flash - but if it's embedded in an HTML page you can overlay a div over the SWF, and control its contents with JS/ExternalInterface. To all intents and purposes the effect is the same, you just need to think about keeping it updated about where it's supposed to be, and what it's supposed to contain.

TextFields do have an html rendering option but I'm not sure how many tags are supported, it's never worked for any that I've tried, and I can't find any ringing endorsements of it on the web.

EDIT - We've recently run into a few problems at work overlaying HTML onto a SWF which has 'wmode' set to 'direct' (which we're doing to implement Stage3D) - some browsers will always render the SWF over everything else if it's set up like this. Unless you're setting this parameter like so it shouldn't trouble you though.